# How do I determine further solutions of the equation using Rolle's theorem?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, roots, rolles-theorem

I gave this equation $2^x=1+x^2$ with the $1$st zero is $x_1=0$ and the $2$nd zero is $x_2=1$. (easy reading)

Now I want to calculate more zeros using Rolle's theorem, and I've rearranged the function for this: $$f(x)=1+x^2-2^x$$

and formed the first two derivatives: $f'(x)=2x-\ln(2)*2^x$ and $f''(x)=2-\ln(2)^2*2^x$

So and from here it fails now. I know what Rolle's theorem says. Between two zeros of the function there is a zero of the derivative, and if $f$ is twice differentiable, then between three zeros of the function there are two zeros of the first derivative and one zero of the second derivative.

Also, I saw that $f(4) > 0$ and $f(5) < 0$. Therefore, in the interval (4,5) there is at least one more zero of $f$ according to the intermediate value theorem.

But how do I determine furthermore precise real solutions of the equation?

Comment: There are no other solutions as $f''(x)$ changes sign once.  To find the root in $(4,5)$ of about $4.2574619$ you can use numerical methods such as interval division or Newton's method

Comment: @Henry thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that most often Rolle's theorem isn't used to prove the existence of solutions, but to show that not too many solutions exist (that said, one *can* in some cases use Rolle's theorem to prove the existence of solutions to $f(x)=0$ if one knows that $f(x)$ is the derivative of some function with appropriate zeros).

You found $3$ solutions using the intermediate value theorem, so we can prove these are the only ones:

The second derivative $f''(x)=2-(\ln 2)^2\cdot 2^x$ has only one root because $f''(x)=0$ implies $2^x = \frac{2}{(\ln 2)^2}$ and $y=2^x$ is injective. Therefore by Rolle's theorem $f'(x)=0$ has at most $2$ solutions (if it had more, $f''(x)=0$ would have more than one solution), and therefore $f(x)=0$ has at most $3$ solutions (if it had more, $f'(x)=0$ would have more than $2$ solutions).